# Compute Hessian matrix for functions that involve matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, calculus

Is it possible to compute the numerical hessian matrix for this function with respect to `W_i`,`C`, `epsilon_i` easily Matlab? I have computed a hessian by manually take a derivative, but I want to verify if my result is correct.

```
W = Nx1;
X = NxM;
X_i = Nx1;
y = 1xM;
C = 1x1;
```

[image: this function]

Comment: A test I've found useful is to, one variable at a time, (numerically) integrate the derivative and compare the result with the difference of the function at the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DERIVEST](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13490) on the file exchange has a function for doing this. There are also tips for doing this eg in Section 18 of [this tutorial](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~spl/MATLAB/matlab.html), or [many other places](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=matlab+hessian).